# Annotation for converting boolean to string in OpenJPA

Tags: openjpa

Good day!

I read this here that using this annotation below:

import org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ExternalValues;
import org.apache.openjpa.persistence.Type;

```
@ExternalValues({"true=T", "false=F"})
@Type(String.class)
private boolean sizeWidth;
```

will enable my JPA to save boolean values from boolean to "T" or "F" on my table. This works beautifully. But now my problem is, what if i have a composite class (embeddable) and it has an boolean as primary key? I used the same approach and declare this annotation to my embeddable but it throws me an error:

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not set boolean field

I know you'll say it is a little bit odd to put boolean as a primary key but it serves its purpose :).

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Please post the entire exception that you're getting.